# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INCLUDE_ONCE

Tags: php, include

the line in question is:

```
include_once 'anotherpage.php';
```

anotherpage.php is fully intact, have no idea what the problem is...also feel free to include a better way to debug php code than coming to people for every little thing. thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code near where this line is placed? This line is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the line that precedes the `include_once()`.  That preceding line probably has a missing semi-colon.

Comment: +1. Beats me why this got downvoted, it's 99.999% likely to be the right answer.

Comment: i would've thought that a comment would have turned the whole thing grey in notepad++, but yeah it was an unstreamed comment for some reason.

Comment: In conclusion, most of the times an "unexpected T_" error appears, it's because it's missing a symbol (semicolon or braces) in a previous line. This is not always true, however, so you should read carefully your code when this happens.

Comment: Just a precursory downvote for the speculation that usually gets posted as a comment. All good with the edit now. Although I still don't know how you figured the preceding line to be the culprit without any code posted.